# Induced tangential structure on manifold boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am referring to (9.61) of Dan Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture9.pdf) which defines the induced tangential structure on manifold boundary.  It says that if $M$ is a manifold with boundary and equipped with an $\mathcal{X}(n)$-structure, then there is an induced $\mathcal{X}(n)$-structure on the boundary by restricting to $\partial{M}$, from the split short exact sequences of tangent bundles

$$ 0 \to T{\partial{M}} \to TM \to \nu \to 0 $$
$$ 0 \to \widetilde{T{\partial{M}}} \to \widetilde{TM} \to \tilde{\nu} \to 0 $$
and the stabilization $\widetilde{TM} = M \times \mathbb{R}^{n-m} \oplus TM$ we can infer that the stabilization for $\widetilde{T\partial{M}}$ is $\widetilde{T\partial{M}} = M \times \mathbb{R}^1 \oplus T\partial{M}$.  This is to say the stabilization for the normal bundle is $\tilde{\nu} = M \times \mathbb{R}^{n-m-1} \oplus \nu$.  But I don't understand why (in fact how $\tilde{\nu}$ is defined).